# Remove rowspan on tables in PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom, html-table

There is this table i want to load into a multi-dimensional array. The problem is that since the table has rowspan values each line may have different cell counts. So i have to remove rowspan and add null values instead of these cells.

This is the table i have(Original file)(Have like 5k rows.)[image: Original Table]

I have to add this table like this in order to have a proper array.[image]

Removing colspan values for the first line was easy. But removing rowspans in current method sometimes cause extra values in array.

My current PHP file for this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M"); 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file('stok.html');

$table = array();
$kac = array();

foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
        $satir = array();
        $j = 0;
        foreach($row->find('td') as $element) {
            if($kac[$j]['deger']>0){
                $satir[]='';
                $kac[$j]['deger']=$kac[$j]['deger']-1;
                $j++;
                while($kac[$j]['deger']>0){
                    $satir[]='';
                    $kac[$j]['deger']=$kac[$j]['deger']-1;
                    $j++;
                }
            }else{
                $j++;
                if(isset($element->rowspan)){
                    $kac[$j]['deger']=($element->rowspan)-1;
                }
                $satir[] = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', strip_tags($element->innertext));
            }

            if(isset($element->colspan)){
                $sayi=($element->colspan)-1;
                for($i=1;$i<=$sayi;$i++){
                    $satir[] = '';
                }
            }
        }
        $table[] = $satir;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($table);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

My Current Output Sample: (See some Array values has 21, 23 and 17 items in it. Correct one is 21 items. (20 as index value)) --Didn't remove the table values in example output--

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>   Envanter (R/B/K)   (Filitre Kodu  :  sa)    (Envanter Tarihi :28/11/2012  )    (Depo : 100)
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Model
            [1] => Stok Adı
            [2] => R
            [3] => Renk Adı
            [4] => B
            [5] => B
            [6] => B
            [7] => B
            [8] => B
            [9] => B
            [10] => B
            [11] => B
            [12] => B
            [13] => B
            [14] => B
            [15] => B
            [16] => B
            [17] => B
            [18] => B
            [19] => Toplam
            [20] => Resim
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 34
            [5] => 36
            [6] => 38
            [7] => 40
            [8] => 42
            [9] => 44
            [10] => 46
            [11] => 48
            [12] => 50
            [13] => 52
            [14] => 54
            [15] => 56
            [16] => 58
            [17] => 60
            [18] => 62
            [19] => Toplam
            [20] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1K011621110
            [1] => NIHAN 2111 KABAN
            [2] => 064
            [3] => FES
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 1.00
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 1.00
            [20] => Resim
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => Toplam :
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 1.00
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 1.00
            [23] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 34
            [2] => 36
            [3] => 38
            [4] => 40
            [5] => 42
            [6] => 44
            [7] => 46
            [8] => 48
            [9] => 50
            [10] => 52
            [11] => 54
            [12] => 56
            [13] => 58
            [14] => 60
            [15] => 62
            [16] => Toplam
            [17] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1K011624760
            [1] => NIHAN 2476 KABAN
            [2] => 001
            [3] => SIYAH
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 1.00
            [10] => 
            [11] => 1.00
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 2.00
            [20] => Resim
        )
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE FOR SOLUTION WITH WORKING CODE:** Currently fills all empty cells with "***"

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M"); 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file('stok.html');

$satir = array();
$rowcount = 0;
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
        $colcount = 0;
        foreach($row->find('td') as $element) {
            while($satir[$rowcount][$colcount]!=''){
                $colcount++;
            }
            $satir[$rowcount][$colcount] = strip_tags(str_replace('&nbsp;', '***', $element->innertext));

            if(isset($element->colspan)){
                $sayi=($element->colspan)-1;
                for($i=1;$i<=$sayi;$i++){
                    $satir[$rowcount][$colcount+$i] = '***';
                }
            }
            if(isset($element->rowspan)){
                $sayi=($element->rowspan)-1;
                for($i=1;$i<=$sayi;$i++){
                    $satir[$rowcount+$i][$colcount] = '***';
                }
            }
            $colcount++;
        }
        $rowcount++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($satir);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: That's pretty tricky. Removing the rowspans already requires you to do some complex calculations to fill up the remaining holes. I'd skip this step and use the same sort of calculations to populate the result array directly. I.e., initialize the result array with all dimensions completely, then go row by row through the table; when you encounter a row/colspan, you can pre-fill related dimensions of the array with the same value...

Comment: Since the values must be in prober order i can not populate array directly. As you said what i am trying to do is removing rowspan and adding null cell values in the correct position until the rowspan ends.

Comment: Yes you can populate it directly, even in the right order. When you traverse through the table, you keep track of the `$x` and `$y` index you're at. When you encounter a rowspan of 2 for example, you set `$result[$x][$y]` and `$result[$x + 1][$y]` to the value of the current cell. When you reach `$x + 1,$y`, the array entry is already populated, which helps you keep track of rowspans while populating the array. That just off the top of my head, but it seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable with a few complications. I will edit my code depending on your idea and share results.

Comment: Please do. If I have some time I'll try my hand on it too... :)

Comment: I followed your idea and reached the solution. Here is the working code: http://pastie.org/private/t8wthg95g2vjx2pxqffcq and i will update my question with the working onw (It currently fills all empty cells with ***. Btw, you can post your suggestion as an answer to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @deceze 's helpful comment, i used a different way to solve the issue. The code below will do the work. But it will fill all empty fields with `***`. You may need to re-visit whole array to empty it after. (The code for this is located below)

```
// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file('stok.html');

$satir = array();
$rowcount = 0;
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
        $colcount = 0;
        foreach($row->find('td') as $element) {
            while($satir[$rowcount][$colcount]!=''){
                $colcount++;
            }
            $satir[$rowcount][$colcount] = strip_tags(str_replace('&nbsp;', '***', $element->innertext));

            if(isset($element->colspan)){
                $sayi=($element->colspan)-1;
                for($i=1;$i<=$sayi;$i++){
                    $satir[$rowcount][$colcount+$i] = '***';
                }
            }
            if(isset($element->rowspan)){
                $sayi=($element->rowspan)-1;
                for($i=1;$i<=$sayi;$i++){
                    $satir[$rowcount+$i][$colcount] = '***';
                }
            }
            $colcount++;
        }
        $rowcount++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($satir);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The code block below will clear the array from those asterisks i mentioned above.

```
$itemcount=count($satir)-1;
for($i=1; $i<=$itemcount; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<=20; $j++){
        if($satir[$i][$j]=='***'){
            $satir[$i][$j]='';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be more helpful in more recent time. We can use a variety of tools that would help us remove merged rows and/or columns like so:

```
<?
namespace app;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\ExcelFactory;

class table {
    private function removeMergedCells(\DOMDocument $dom): \DOMDocument
    {
        $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
        $search = $xpath->query('//table');

        /** @var \DOMNode $node */
        foreach ($search as $node) {
            $html = $dom->saveXML($node);

            $tmpHtml = \tempnam(\sys_get_temp_dir(), 'html');
            $tmpTable = \tempnam(\sys_get_temp_dir(), 'table');

            \file_put_contents($tmpHtml, $html);

            $table = ExcelFactory::load($tmpHtml);
            $merged = ($table->getAllSheets())[0]->getMergeCells();

            foreach ($merged as $cell) {
                $table->getActiveSheet()->unmergeCells($cell);
            }

            // this $writerType is case sensitive
            $writer = ExcelFactory::createWriter($table, 'Html');

            $writer->save($tmpTable);

            $domNew = new \DOMDocument();
            $domNew->loadHTML(\file_get_contents($tmpTable));

            $nodeNew = $dom->importNode($domNew->getElementsByTagName('body')[0], true);
            $node->parentNode->replaceChild($nodeNew, $node);
        }

        return $dom;
    }
}
?>
```